# In Javascript, does the await in the main program causes the program to block?

Tags: javascript, c#, asynchronous, async-await

In C#, the await inside the function causes control to return to the caller. Where as await in the main program causes the program to block.

In Javascript, the await inside the function causes control to return to the caller. Does the await in the main program causes the program to block?

Comment: You cannot use `await` in "the main program". Top-level `await` is only available in *modules* which makes it an async module.

Comment: C# `await` doesn't really "block" so much as suspend the execution until the task completes.